# How to active the previous page primary button to work properly as it were doing before clicking it?

Tags: javascript, html

Full Scenario:
On the order page, I need to connect the "Continue" button to a booking page.

On the booking page, I desire that when the user returns to the previous order page using the browser's back button, the user should still be able to move between these two pages without any hindrances. What happens is the "Continue" button on the order page becomes inactive i.e. preventing further navigation.

Please help me create a script to achieve this thing.
Thanks.

I have tried the JavaScript performance feature to detect that user has pressed browser's back button to go back to previous page and reload the page so that it's each and every element become active to regain all their abilities to function properly.
But it is not working still as I want it to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function handleContinueButtonClick() {
    localStorage.setItem("continueClicked", true);
    window.location.href = 'https://www.website.com/go-to-booking';
  }

  var continueButton = document.querySelector('.shlGd4v [data-hook="FormDetailsButtons.continue"]');

  // Check if the page is loaded due to history traversal
  var historyTraversal = window.performance && window.performance.navigation && window.performance.navigation.type === 2;

  if (historyTraversal) {
    // Page is reloaded after navigating back
   /* This condition is not being satisfied for history traversal, right now*/
    continueButton.addEventListener("click", handleContinueButtonClick);
    console.log('Page was reloaded after navigating back');
  } else {
    // Page is loaded normally
    continueButton.addEventListener("click", handleContinueButtonClick);
    console.log('Page was loaded normally');
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage, below is an example.

```
    // Check if the page was reloaded after the back button is pressed
if (performance.navigation.type === 2) {
    // User navigated back, so restore the state
    var continueClicked = localStorage.getItem("continueClicked");
    if (continueClicked === "true") {
        // "Continue" button was clicked, make necessary adjustments
        // For example, enable the button or perform any required actions
    }
}

function handleContinueButtonClick() {
    localStorage.setItem("continueClicked", true);
    window.location.href = 'https://www.website.com/go-to-booking';
}

// Add an event listener to the "Continue" button
var continueButton = document.querySelector("#continueButton"); // Replace with the actual ID or selector
if (continueButton) {
    continueButton.addEventListener("click", handleContinueButtonClick);
}
```

Make sure to replace #continueButton with the actual ID or selector of your "Continue" button. This script checks if the page was reloaded after a back navigation and, if so, restores the state based on the continueClicked value in localStorage.

Also, ensure that your "Continue" button is being properly enabled or activated based on the localStorage value in your page's initialization logic.